Coroutines don't advance when testing Ktor with Jetpack Compose
I'm trying to test my code that uses Ktor:
WeatherRepository:
class WeatherRepository(
engine: HttpClientEngine,
private val locationClient: LocationClient
) {
...

suspend fun getCurrentWeather(): CurrentWeather {
    val coordinates = locationClient.getCoordinates()
    val requestUrl = "forecast?current_weather=true&latitude=${coordinates.lat}&longitude=${coordinates.lon}"
    val response = httpClient.get(requestUrl)
    println(response)
    ....
}

HomeRepository:
class HomeRepository(
private val weatherRepository: WeatherRepository
)  {
    suspend fun getCurrentWeather(): CurrentWeather {
        return weatherRepository.getCurrentWeather()
    }
}

HomeViewModel:
class HomeViewModel(
private val homeRepository: HomeRepository
): ViewModel() {
...
private fun getCurrentWeather(refresh: Boolean) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            val weather = homeRepository.getCurrentWeather()
            _uiState.update { it.copy(currentWeather = weather) }
        } catch (e: Exception) { 
            ...
        }
    }
}

MainDispatcherRule:
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class MainDispatcherRule(
val testDispatcher: TestDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()
) : TestWatcher() {
override fun starting(description: Description) {
    Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
}

override fun finished(description: Description) {
    Dispatchers.resetMain()
}
}

Then I use this rule in the test (view model is initialized inside of homeBaseRule):
@get: Rule(order = 0)
val dispatcherRule = MainDispatcherRule()
@get: Rule(order = 1)
val homeBaseRule = HomeBaseRule()

Then I execute advanceUntilIdle() after calling viewmodel's getCurrentWeather, but the code after val response = httpClient.get(requestUrl) executes only if i call advanceUntilIdle() lots of times
@Test
fun fetchCurrentWeather_success() = runTest(dispatcherRule.testDispatcher) {
    homeBaseRule.viewModel.handleIntent(HomeIntent.GetCurrentWeather)
    advanceUntilIdle()

EDIT
I spent some more time testing the app and found that calling the repository method directly from a test doesn't feature the above issue:
@Test
fun test() = runTest {
    homeBaseRule.setupHomeRepository(suggestionsGenerationException = homeBaseRule.exception)
    val weather = homeBaseRule.homeRepository.getCurrentWeather()
    assertTrue(weather != null)
}


Can you share the code of your test where the advanceUntilIdle method is called?

Tests won't work when you create a new CoroutineScope by adding a SupervisorJob to test's TestScope. If possible inject CoroutineScope directly instead of using CoroutineScopeProvider:
class HomeViewModel(
    private val homeRepository: HomeRepository,
    private val scope: CoroutineScope,
) : ViewModel() {

    private fun getCurrentWeather() {
        scope.launch {
            //...
        }
    }
}

Test:
@Test
fun theTest() = runTest {
    //...
    val viewModel = HomeViewModel(repo, this)
    viewModel.getCurrentWeather()
}

Or you could just remove + SupervisorJob() in CoroutineScopeProvider, but then what's the point of CoroutineScopeProvider at all? To be honest the whole CoroutineScopeProvider construct seems dubious to me.
Explanation
Testing
I assume that the test is wrapped with runTest. In this case creating a new TestScope is unnecessary and defeats the purpose of runTest which creates its own TestScope which should be used for the coroutines being tested. Also, unless you are setting the Main dispatcher, you should specify a scheduler for StandardTestDispatcher. With that in mind your test would look like this:
val dispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher(testScheduler)
val coroutineScopeProvider = CoroutineScopeProvider(this, dispatcher)

Adding Job to TestScope
But even now the test won't work like you expect. When you create a new CoroutineScope and add a SupervisorJob, it breaks parent-child relation of the test's TestScope. Any newly created coroutine will have this SupervisorJob as its parent and TestScope's job won't know about them and won't wait for them to complete. Read more it the docs.
To visualise this you can add the following into the HomeViewModel:
fun getCurrentWeather() {
    scope.launch {
        println("Parent job: ${this.coroutineContext.job.parent}")
    //...

Run the test, it should print something like Parent job: SupervisorJobImpl{Active}@21694e53. Now remove + SupervisorJob() in CoroutineScopeProvider and run the test again, it should print Parent job: TestScope[test started].
On an unrelated note: this test seems too vague, what exactly are you testing - HomeViewModel, HomeRepository, WeatherRepository?

Basically I'm testing all of those.
I agree that CoroutineScopeProvider is ambiguous, so I've tried inserting the coroutine scope directly into the view model: externalCoroutineScope: CoroutineScope? = null, and then replacing it with the test scope: private val scope = externalCoroutineScope ?: viewModelScope, but now I'm getting java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Parent job is Cancelling. Also I've injected test scheduler into the distpatcher: val dispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher(TestCoroutineScheduler())

If you don't use CoroutineScopeProvider anymore, have you tried using viewModelScope directly and replacing Main dispatcher like described here? @YauheniMokich

Yes, I've copy-pasted the MainDispatcherRule, tried using StandardTestDispatcher and UnconfinedTestDispatcher, but to no avail. I think the issue is specifically related to ktor since both the CoroutineScopeProvider and MainDispatcherRule approaches worked in tests not related to it. @Jan Itor

OK It's getting difficult to keep track of the exact implementation you have. From the solution oriented point of view I would recommend creating separate tests for HomeViewModel and the repositories. It would make everything easier and is just a cleaner approach overall. @YauheniMokich

Ok, I spent some time developing and testing the app, and found that calling the repository method directly in the unit test doesn't feature this issue
@Test     fun test() = runTest {         homeBaseRule.setupHomeRepository(suggestionsGenerationException = homeBaseRule.exception)         val weather = homeBaseRule.homeRepository.getCurrentWeather(false)         advanceUntilIdle()         assertTrue(weather != null)     }
@Jan Itor
